# Discord.py Mute Command Channel Permissions

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a `>>setup mute` command, it creates a role Muted and i need it to create channel permissions for every channel for that role, but its only setting permissions for the channel that i run `>>setup mute` in, and it sets the channel permissions for the @everyone role not the Muted role. Can someone help?
Heres my code

```
  elif command.lower() == 'mute':
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Muted')
    if role in ctx.guild.roles:
      await ctx.send('Already Setup')
    else:
      perms = discord.Permissions(send_messages=False, read_messages=True)
      role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name='Muted', permissions=perms)
      muted = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Muted')
      for muted in ctx.guild.roles:
        await ctx.channel.set_permissions(muted, send_messages=False, read_messages=True, read_message_history=True)
      await ctx.send('Muted Role Created')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesnt work. Is that you iterate over each role and use the same channel. Then setting the permission to mute someone with all the roles in the server, with the same channel. This results into every role being muted in a single channel:

```
muted = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Muted')
for muted in ctx.guild.roles:
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(muted, send_messages=False, read_messages=True, read_message_history=True)
```

Another problem is that the variable muted is shadowed by the variable muted created by the for loop. Because of this shadowing, the first line wont be used. Thus the muted role you have gotten is not used at all.

What you need to do next time is to select a role. But then iterate over every channel of the guild instead of the roles of the server (Then applying the permissions of that role in all channels.):

```
for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
    channel.set_permissions(muted, send_messages=False, read_messages=True, read_message_history=True)
```